# WPF User control or Template? How would i create a Template using Blend?

Tags: wpf, templates, expression-blend

How would i create a window template using Blend? My application will be sharing many pages with the same layout.

One of my major concerns is what will happen when i need to make a change to the template. Will this update all of the pages automatically? Should i just use a usercontrol and add it to everypage?

Answer (score 1):

Stay away from UserControls, generally.  Instead, you want to use ControlTemplates, and put them in Resource Dictionary files, which you can [totally make with Blend](http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=384).